# Pyqt application crashed with killed message

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

I have PyQt application which used to display large data into qplain textedit. I am facing issue or doing some fundamental mistake. it is my first qt project so i did some blunder

*Main issue*

1. I am able to load data and it work well follow below approach.
   [QPlainTextEdit consume large memory for large string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70418334/qplaintextedit-consume-large-memory-for-large-string)
   **But suddenly after 2 to 3 mintue pyqt application got crashed with *killed* message and not any other info.** without any operation (or click)

I have checked cpu utilization and memory usage was also low. any idea to debug/module which can provide detailed info.

2. I have tried to simulate all whole and create runable program and have following query
3. can I pass app argument to class
4. Fin class does not invoking eventfilter

Overview: I have written Finclass which inherits QMainWindow
mainwidget is generated when we insert tab.
So purpose was, toolbar will common for all tab and create widget for each tab.

I hope I am able to provide some context

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import PySide2
print (PySide2.__file__)
from PySide2.QtCore import QEvent, QSize
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QPlainTextEdit, QApplication, QSplitter, QTabWidget, QToolBar)


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        super().__init__()
        ## set variable an pass data model object which contain file path

    def create_widget(self):
        self.create_violation_text()

        main_window = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plain_textedit)
        # creating widgeth object as main window does not
        # add layout direct to own layout
        main_window.addWidget(main_layout)
        blk_window = QWidget()
        blk_window.setLayout(main_window)
        return blk_window

    def create_violation_text(self):
        """
        creating main violation window which contain all violations
        """
        self.plain_textedit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plain_textedit.setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.plain_textedit.setStyleSheet(
            """QPlainTextEdit {font-size: 14pt;
                               font-family: Courier;}""")
        self.plain_textedit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plain_textedit.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.plain_textedit_format = self.plain_textedit.currentCharFormat()
        self.plain_textedit.setCursorWidth(5)

        self.plain_textedit.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.plain_textedit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        print ("event", obj)
        if obj is self.plain_textedit.viewport() and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print ("text edit event")
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class FinWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = 1100
        self.height = 700
        self.set_main_window()
        self.blk_obj = MainWidget(app)
        self.app = app


    def set_main_window(self):
        """
        Setting main window position
        """
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI %s" % (os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(self.width, self.height))
        wid = QDesktopWidget()
        screen_width = wid.screen().frameGeometry().width()
        screen_height = wid.screen().frameGeometry().height()
        self.setGeometry(screen_width / 2 - self.width / 2,
                         screen_height / 2 - self.height / 2,
                         self.width, self.height)

    def create_menu(self):
        """
        Adding toolbar option
        :return:
        """
        self.toolbar = QToolBar()

    def eventfilter(self):
        print ("finale filter")


    def create_window(self):

        self.create_menu()
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab_widget.tabBar().setObjectName("mainTab")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.blk_obj.create_widget(), "test")

        main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)

    def run(self):
        self.create_window()
        self.show()
        self.app.exec_()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    fin = FinWindow(app)
    fin.run()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash with the provided code (and there seem to be no reason for which it should happen). Besides: 1. the purpose of `MainWidget` is unclear, since you're *not* using that widget but only its functions; 2. if with "Fin class does not invoking eventfilter" you mean that the function `eventfilter` of `FinWindow` is never called, then that's correct: there's absolutely no reference to that function in your code, so it's unclear why you would expect it to be called; 3. you should not call the application `exec` inside a widget class;

Comment: 4. both [`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) and [`height()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop) are dynamic properties of all widgets and you shall not overwrite them; 5. QDesktopWidget is obsolete, use [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) instead; 6. the size policy of QPlainTextEdit (as for all Qt scroll areas) is already expanding in both directions; 7. always try to provide a proper *[mre]*: yours is not minimal (many parts of the code are completely irrelevant for the problem) nor reproducible (the problem cannot be reproduced).

Comment: I want to set window size, than how can i set, one more thing. does pyqt have api/class which can print traceback along with killed. can i pass into fin class.

Comment: the purpose of mainwidget class, creating plaintext layout and inserting as tab, so another tab come, just need to invoke main widget class. ( support multiple tab with same functionality). can widget have eventfilter? mainwidget is composition inside fin class. should i define eventfilter for fin class than redirect to mainwidget.

Comment: 1. just use another name, like `self._width` and `self._height`; 2. run the program in a terminal or prompt; 3. get the program arguments with `sys.args` or get the [`app.arguments()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments); 4. the purpose of a QWidget is to be shown and used in the UI, your `MainWidget` is *never* used for that purpose, so it's completely pointless to create a class for that, especially considering that the widgets you're creating are used elsewhere: remove it and move its functions inside the `FinWindow` class;

Comment: you mean, remove Mainwindow. it is big class. i have added image of real tool. disable some color due to privacy

Comment: for me strange thing, gui open if i leave for 2 to 3 it get killed

Comment: The point remains: that function returns a widget that is *not* used in that class. And that's probably the reason for which you get that crash: you're creating widgets dynamically for which you keep a persistent reference to the *last* one only, and that are not properly destroyed/updated. The code you're providing does *not* that, it only creates a *single* widget, and will *not* crash, meaning that it's *not* a reproducible example. Don't tell us that your program crashes, ensure that your example does, this means *reproducibility*. We cannot fix something that has errors somewhere else.

Comment: ok u mean, self.blk_obj is not used. But iI am using and insertin to tab. am i missing your statement. self.tab_widget.addTab(self.blk_obj.create_widget(), "test"). self.blk_obj.create_widget() will use widget am i right?

Comment: You're just using a function of that object, according to your code that object is *not* used as a widget (a main window), but just as a container for the functions you're calling and that return *another* widget that has practically no relation with it. *If* you're using it in your program as an actual widget, then it *may* have sense, but you should not use nor overwrite the `self.plain_textedit` reference if you're calling `create_widget()` more than once, as that is certainly one source of your problem. But, as said, this is irrelevant, with the current code, we cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @musicamante, Thanks a lot for your words... your suggestion works for me... once thx again. please share your experience how you become expert